# Error when accessing downloaded files on Android

Tags: android

I'm running into a problem in my Android Application where whenever I tried to load a file that I have downloaded from email, I'm receiving a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` error.  This is weird, because the file is clearly showing up in the "Downloads" list, but it does not seem to be found when my app tries to open it.  The error references a "/document" directory which does not physically exists on the device.  This sort of seems like it could be related to some mechanism for passing files via intents, but I'm missing something.  I am trying this on both a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 running 4.4.2 as well as different versions of the Android Emulator.  I'm getting the same problem everywhere I look.  Below, I have included the error message.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks!!!

> 11-07 23:23:13.324 12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity:
>   File select error 11-07 23:23:13.324 12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy
>   E/ImportActivity: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/1677: open
>   failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) 11-07 23:23:13.324
>   12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity:     at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409) 11-07 23:23:13.324
>   12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity:     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:78) 11-07
>   23:23:13.324 12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity:     at
>   java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:42) 11-07 23:23:13.324
>   12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity:     at
>   com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy.ImportActivity.onActivityResult(ImportActivity.java:210)
>   11-07 23:23:13.324 12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity: 
>   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5643)
>   11-07 23:23:13.324 12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity: 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3677)
>   11-07 23:23:13.324 12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity: 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3724)
>   11-07 23:23:13.324 12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity: 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:175)
>   11-07 23:23:13.324 12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity: 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
>   11-07 23:23:13.324 12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity: 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 11-07
>   23:23:13.324 12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 11-07 23:23:13.324
>   12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 11-07
>   23:23:13.324 12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-07
>   23:23:13.324 12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 11-07 23:23:13.324
>   12193-12193/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy E/ImportActivity:     at

Comment: Show us your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: You can share the code snippet with us. It's clear indicate that it could not able to open or find directory or file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 /document/1677
```

That is not a file system path but a part of a content provider path.

You will see the complete path with url.getPath().

You can open an input stream to the document with

```
getContentResolver.openStream(url);
```

Comment: That was it!  I changed my final `File file = FileUtils.getFile(uri);` to `InputStream input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);` (and added the appropriate readers around them) and everything worked perfectly.  Thanks!